# How to write a prolog mathematical Function?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to convert a math function into prolog, but I keep getting error. Can anyone give me a hint that where is my mistake, please?

I want to convert f (x) = x ˆ 2 + f (x - 1). So I am assuming that this is a recursive procedure. Here is What I have done so far.

```
function(0,0) :- !.
function(1,1) :- !.
function(X,Y) :-
   X1 is ((X * X) + (X - 1)),
   function(X1, Y).
```

I have also tried

```
function(0,0) :- !.
function(1,1) :- !.
function(X,Y) :- 
  X1 is (X * X), X2 is (X - 1),
  function(X1, N1),
  function(X2, N2),
  Y is N1 + N2.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prolog works using predicate calculus.
A predicate can evaluate to true or false.

You need to write what is true (anything else is assumed false as prolog interpreters will use a closed world assumption).

for your function we can define a predicate:

func(X, Y)

where func is a predicate that evaluates to true if X is x and Y is f(X)
You need to tell prolog when func(X, Y) is true

```
func(0, 0).
func(X, Y) :- X > 0, U is X - 1, func(U, V), Y is X * X + V.
```

The above code can be thought of saying
your predicate func is true when X is 0 and Y is 0

This will be your base case. (You only need one since you only have 1 recursive call).

Next is your recursive case:

When is func true for a general X

- we need X to be greater than 0
- we need the result of f(x-1) which we called V
- V is the result of f(X-1) when func(X-1, V) is true
- prolog doesn't allow expressions inside predicates so we state U is X-1
- Then we put everything together and state Y is X *X + V

Comment: Thanks Timothy for you explantation, very clear and simple. It now makes more sense!

Comment: No problem, I find it easier to figure out how to write prolog by thinking you're not telling prolog how to find the answer, you're telling it what the answer looks like.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
f(0,0) .        % f(0) is 0.
f(X,Y) :-       % otherwise...
  integer(X) ,  % - constrain X to be an integer, and
  X > 0 ,       % - constrain X to be positive,
  X1 is X-1 ,   # - then decrement X
  f(X1,Y1) ,    % - compute f(X-1) ,
  Y is X*X + Y1 % - and add X*X to that to get the result.
  .             % Easy!
```